# Magento 2 How to duplicate Categories with Assigning all products and children categories

Tags: magento2, category

I am looking for a solution to duplicate category including all settings, products and all children categories.

I have researched on the forum and found some extensions which are paid.

https://marketplace.magento.com/mageside-module-duplicatecategory.html

Can anybody help to achieve this by programmatically or suggest for a free module?

Comment: There is no free extension for this but another paid one which you can consider is [this one](https://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-2-duplicate-category.html) by FMEextensions. It offers even more features like maintaining product rules and text replace etc, in addition to copying parent, categories, sub-categories with products.

Comment: One would think there will be a query, might by a large query, but some sort of SQL that we enter the category id and it duplicate it. But then you start realizing how magento works and to consider it as a valid solution, not just a quick hack, it has to copy the correct things, now there are a lot of settings associated with categories, product sorting, not to mention multiple stores.

Comment: It's hard to find a free module but there is a paid module [Duplicate Category](https://www.mageants.com/duplicate-category-for-magento-2.html) from `Mageants`, which will provide you the features like duplicating categories with the same configuration settings for all subcategories and also duplicates the parent categories, all subcategories, copy product relation of subcategory and sub-categories rules, and control product relations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no free extension for this but another paid one which you can consider is [Duplicate Categories](https://marketplace.magento.com/fme-copy-category.html) by FMEextensions. It offers even more features like maintaining product rules and text replacement etc, in addition to copying parent, categories, and sub-categories with products.